# Extract value of a dynamic key from response

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a response as below:

```
{
    "value": {
        "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "b721a18e-ffab-49bc-acdf-5a30c84e160d"
    }
}
```

I want to extract the value of they dynamic key labelled "element-6066-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx" (changes each time I re-run the API call).

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried the following:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("elementId", Object.keys(data.value)[0]);
```

But this sets the "key" instead of the "value" (expecting 'b721a18e-ffab-49bc-acdf-5a30c84e160d' to be set.

Comment: What's this got to do with Groovy?  It's javascript isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `Object.values()` for this:

```js
let res = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("elementId", Object.values(res.value)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.values()` would help you. you can refer to this [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). Here is an example of that:

```js
let x = {
    "value": {
        "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "b721a18e-ffab-49bc-acdf-5a30c84e160d"
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(x.value)[0])
```

Comment: This is still logging out the `key` and not the `value`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I suggested to use values but kept the keys in the logs lol, just changed it to values!